# How do you create lists using js or a simple way to list whatever was submitted in an input tag, and color it?

Tags: javascript

For context, just starting with JS, and wanted to do something simple, create a Higher/Lower guessing game. I have it fully working, though I wanted to add some more color to it, so my idea is to create a list of previously guessed numbers and whether that number is higher or lower than the target number (the number that they have to guess). though I currently have it set up where

```
const guesses = document.querySelector(".guesses");
```

and

```
guesses.textContent += userGuess + ' ';
```

so it just creates this extremely long, sentence-like line of previously guessed numbers that is in all white. Is there any way for me to change it so that each individual guess can somehow be listed and can be either red or green depending on if the target number is higher or lower?

For the if, else, and else if statements, I just have it so that it shows a certain text stating if the guess is too high or too low, and if it's exact, then it gives the option to restart the game

Edit, more parts of the code:
js:

```
let userGuess = guessField.valueAsNumber
const guessField = document.getElementById('guessField');
```

guessField is just an input tag in HTML

then in js, I have it generate some number, save that as `randomNumber` with `let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1)`

then if userGuess === randomNumber then show a p tag saying that it's right, and give it a green background or else say it's wrong (that p tag). Then I have it look if the userGuess number is lower or higher than the target number (aka the randomNumber) if it's too high, show a paragraph saying it's too high, and if it's too low, show a paragraph saying it's too low.

Comment: Add [Minimal, Reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can understand it better and help you accordingly

Comment: @decpk just added a bit more of the code I used

Answer (score 0):

Add guesses in a list instead of just as text in a div. Add backgroundColor style to the result p tag to show whether guess is higher or lower or correct.

```js
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1)

const guesses = document.querySelector("#guesses");
const result = document.querySelector("#result");

function checkNum() {
  let guessField = document.getElementById('guessField');
  let userGuess = parseInt(guessField.valueAsNumber, 10);
  var node = document.createElement("li");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(userGuess);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  guesses.appendChild(node);
  guessField.value = "";
  result.style.backgroundColor = "tomato";
  if (userGuess === randomNumber) {
    result.style.backgroundColor = "aquamarine";
    result.innerHTML = "You are right";
  } else if (userGuess < randomNumber) {
    result.innerHTML = "Guess is lower";
  } else {
    result.innerHTML = "Guess is higher";
  }

}
```

```css
p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul id="guesses">
</ul>
<input type="number" id="guessField" />
<button onclick="checkNum()">check</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have very minimal info here on what you would like to accomplish and the code you are using however I think we'll be able to help you out here :)

there are a few approaches you can take here, I'm not sure if you're using any databases for your use case but since you're starting off I'm going to assume you simply want to store the values submitted via the input field in an array and later iterate through the array in an effort to pull values from it and perform operations with each iteration.

first you would need to declare an array:

```
const guessedNumbers = [];
```

next to store the values from user input you would need to to create a submit event listener on your form that will invoke a function to store the value user submits in the guessedNumbers array. In order to store the values in the guessedNumbers array you can use the .push method:

```
form = document.querySelector('your-form-selector');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  const userInputValue = document.querySelector('your-input-field-selector').value;

  guessedNumbers.push(userInputValue);
});
```

Now if you need to access the values stored in the guessedNumbers array, there are multiple built in methods that allow you to accomplish this. Have a look at this MDN link that will shed some light on these array methods. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

for example you may want to iterate through each value in the array and console.log each iteration's value:

```
guessedNumbers.forEach((number) => console.log(number))
```

Happy coding!